# Hadoop MapReduce, how to reduce a custom object?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and i am trying to play around with the Reducer class.
So, basically i found a tutorial online where their reduce class looks like this,

```
public class mapReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
    IntWritable total = new IntWritable();
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Reducer<Text, InWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        for (IntWritable value: values){
             total += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, count);
    }
}
```

So i want to change the total with `myCustomObj`. Referring to above example, something like,

```
//..
myCustomObj total = new myCustomObj();
@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<myCustomObj> values,
        Reducer<Text, InWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    for (myCustomObj value: values){
         total.add(value);
    }
    context.write(key, total.getPrimaryAttribute());
}
```

**Objective:** What i want is the **list** of `key -> total` objects after hadoop have finished reducing. I think the above code will only output `key -> primaryAttribute`.

**Suggestion:** If this is too tedious, i have an idea of storing the details i need on disk in XML format. However, i am not sure about the theory behind map reducer, does the reducer execute in the server or the client computers (where the mapping takes place)? If it happens in the client computers, then i would have little bit and pieces of my XML files on all the client computers. I just want all the information centralized into 1 server.

I hope i made my question clear. Thank you

**EDIT:** I tried to look for online sources. But there are many customization of hadoops. I have no idea what should i look at.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. What does the implementation of `myCustomObj` look like?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to reduce a custom object, first of all, you mapper should be returning this objects as a value. Assuming that the name of your object is: `CustomObject` the mapper definition should look like:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, CustomObject> {
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, CustomObject>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // do you stuff here
    }
}
```

Now the CustomObject itself should be implementing the `WritableComparable` interface with all the three required methods (mainly for the shuffling phase requirements):

- `write` - defines the way your objects is stored to the disk
- `readFields` - how to read the stored object from the disk
- `compareTo` - defines the way how the objects should be sorted (you can leave this blank, as only keys are being used for sorting during the shuffle phase)

Reducer signature should look like:

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, CustomObject, Text, IntWritable>{
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<CustomObject> values,
            Reducer<Text, CustomObject, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        // reducer code
    }
}
```

Finally when configuring the job, you should specify proper input/output combination.

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(CustomObject.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
```

This should do the trick.